# Centering hit area around RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I have a radio group with 2 radio buttons without text. In the following, I will describe everything in very detail and show everything I have tried. The layout looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:scaleX="2"
            android:scaleY="2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:scaleX="2"
            android:scaleY="2" />
    </RadioGroup>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

As can be seen, the hit (clickable) area covers exactly the buttons (shown as blue rectangle).

Now I would like to increase the size of the clickable area. When I add             `android:paddingTop="30dp"` and `android:paddingBottom="30dp"` to each button I'm getting the following layout:

[image]

This is nice, now the clickable area is enlarged at the top and bottom. But I would also like to expand the clickable area to the left and right. So I add `android:paddingLeft="30dp"` to each button. The result is the following:

[image]

That is bad because the clickable area (blue rectangles) is now no more centered around the button. When I add `android:paddingRight="30dp"` to each button (which is equivalend to substituting all above paddings with just android:padding="30dp") it gets even worse:

[image]

I have tried everything but I'm not able to get the clickable area centered around the button. So I have tried to move the clickable area at runtime using

```
RadioButton radioButton= findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
final View parent = (View) radioButton.getParent();
parent.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final Rect rect = new Rect();
        radioButton.getHitRect(rect);
        rect.left -= 100;
        rect.right -= 100;
        parent.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(rect, radioButton));
    }
});
```

This does also not work, the clickable area somehow does not change at all.

Is there any way to get the clickable area centered around the buttons? Any help is highly appreciated.